# How can code in a JavaScript file get the file's URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, cross-domain

I need to dynamically load a CSS stylesheet into a page that's on a *different* domain. How can I get the complete URL of the JS file to use in the **href** attribute of the stylesheet?

For instance, here is the structure:

`http://bla.com/js/script.js`

`http://bla.com/css/style.css`

I want to dynamically load the stylesheet into a page **http://boo.net/index.html**. The problem is, I don't know the **bla.com** bit in advance, just the fact that the stylesheet is in **../css/** relative to the JS file.

The script is, of course, included on **index.html**. jQuery's fine too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add an ID to the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="myScript" src="http://bla.com/js/script.js"></script>
```

And in `http://bla.com/js/script.js`:

```
var myScript = document.getElementById('myscript');
var myScriptSrc = myScript.getAttribute('src');
alert(myScriptSrc); // included for debugging
```

You should be able to manipulate the value of `myScriptSrc` to obtain the path to any other content on `bla.com`.

I think this sample is what [James Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279195/how-can-code-in-a-javascript-file-get-the-files-url/1279277#1279277) meant in his answer.

Lastly, to everyone suggesting the use of `document.location`, please keep in mind that if you want read-only access to the current page address, you should be using `document.URL` or `window.location`. If you want to set the page address, you should always use `window.location.href`. Although `window.location = 'location';` works, it has always bothered me to see a String being assigned to a Location. I'm not sure why since JavaScript allows all sorts of other implicit type conversions.

- [mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.location): `document.location` was originally a read-only property, although Gecko browsers allow you to assign to it as well. For cross-browser safety, use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) instead. To retrieve just the URL as a string, the read-only [document.URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.URL) property can be used.
- [Sun reference](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/document.htm): Do not use [location](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/location.htm) as a property of the `document` object; use the [document.URL](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/document.htm#1194041) property instead. The `document.location` property, which is a synonym for `document.URL`, is deprecated.

Comment: Nice. Minor aside: [officially, HTML4 does not allow an id in `<script>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686150/script-tags-with-ids/). HTML5 does.

Answer (score 19):

Even easier than using an `id` is to just leave the markup alone and use [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.currentScript). The link to MDN mentions under the [**Notes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript#Notes) section, a small quirk requiring the JavaScript to execute synchronously, and I'm about to explain how to avoid this pitfall.

> It's important to note that this will not reference the `<script>` element if the code in the script is being called as a callback or event handler; it will only reference the element while it's initially being processed.

The advantage of this solution is that you are not required to use special markup, and this is especially helpful if you can't access the HTML yourself for some reason (e.g. if it's used by a client or a developer using your API).

If the script is executed synchronously (meaning the main content of the script isn't wrapped in an event listener or some other function set to evaluate later than when the code is *"initially being processed"* ), you can simply use `document.currentScript` to access the currently processing `<script>` element of your code. To demonstrate how to use this effectively, I'll provide a basic demo below.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bla.com/js/script.js"></script>
```

JavaScript in `http://bla.com/js/script.js`:

```
var myScript = document.currentScript,
    mySrc = myScript.getAttribute('src');

console.log(mySrc); // "http://bla.com/js/script.js"

$(function () {
    // your other code here, assuming you use jQuery
    // ...
});
```

If you don't want the variable to be exposed to the global scope, you can also do this:

```
(function () {
    var myScript = document.currentScript,
        mySrc = myScript.getAttribute('src');

    console.log(mySrc); // "http://bla.com/js/script.js"

    $(function () {
        // your other code here
        // ...
    });
}()); // self-executing anonymous function
```

Basically the point is to make sure and access `document.currentScript` during synchronous execution of the script, otherwise it will not reference what you expect it to.

Comment: Not supported in IE 11.

Answer (score 7):

With Jquery, you could do something like:

```
$('script[src$="my_script.js"]').attr('src').replace('my_script.js','');
// outputs something like: "/static/js/"
```

Comment: Very useful when there's no id on the script tag and it's a partner's code where you can't have a DOM id added.

Answer (score 6):

```
var JS_SELF_URL = (function() {
    var script_tags = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    return script_tags[script_tags.length-1].src;
})();
```

As the browser parses  tags, it also downloads and executes them. Therefore when your JS file is executed it is currently the last  tag parsed.

Comment: Avoid this when using `async` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You could look in the script tag for the javascript location, and by using document.location you could probably determine the relative addressing, in order to determine where the css file may be.

Answer (score 0):

Stack property of error objects can provide URL information.

```
try 
{ 
  throw new Error();
}
catch(exc)
{
  console.log(exc.stack);
}
```

Unfortunately, Webkit doesn't (but Chromium does) support stack property. There are a few browsers supporting this feature: http://173.45.237.168/reference/html/api/Error.html#Error.stack

Instead of stack, Webkit provides  sourceURL property, here is the exampe usage:

```
try 
{ 
  throw new Error();
}
catch(exc)
{
  console.log(exc.sourceURL);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can read `document.location`, but you could also just use relative URLs

Comment: As far as I know, document.location returns the URI of the current document, not the JS file inside which the code is executing.