# Script tags with IDs?

Tags: html

Do most modern browsers support ids in script tags such as:

```
<script id="aParticularScript">/* ... */</script>
```

The reason I ask is that Eclipse displays a warning stating "undefined attribute name" but it works fine in Google Chrome when I use jQuery selectors to get other properties of the script element. W3Schools states that the script element does not support any standard attributes (including the id attribute), but I've learned not to trust W3Schools.

Is it okay to have the script tag have an id?

Comment: At least in HTML 4, the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html) don't show an `id` attribute.

Comment: Apparently jQuery Templates use script tags with ids: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

Comment: Do those `id`s actually appear in the output, or are they just parsed by the template plugin to produce some other output? Is this your reason for asking? If not, why *do* you want to give an `id` to a script tag?

Comment: The examples on the jQuery site you're referring to are `type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"`, which are technically not the same as `text/javascript` elements.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: But they are still script elements.

Comment: @Madmartigan - Except that the HTML 4 spec allows for a `type` attribute, but not an `id`. If one is acceptable (`id` and `type`), I would suspect it's by a different doctype than HTML 4.

Comment: By the way, a fantastic alternative to W3Schools (which you rightfully don't trust) is the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). All of its pages include links to the actual relevant specifications, as well, which is extremely helpful. (Tip: appending "mdn" to google searches usually pushes it up to the top of the results)

Comment: @Madmartigan - "I've never heard of one attribute being OK only if another is present" - Actually, there's a fair amount of this in HTML5, especially around the `<input>` element. For example, for each input type attribute value, there's a whole list of other attributes that must not be specified. In HTML4, I believe that DTD's don't provide a way of specifying that, so even if HTML4 made such rules, an SGML-based validator would not be able to spot violations.

Comment: @Alohci: Good call, you're right. Like `checked` makes no sense (I assume it's invalid) if `type` is `text`, for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HTML 4 Answer:**

No, you can't, at least not if you want valid HTML...

The following elements can't have an ID attribute:

- `<base>`
- `<head>`
- `<html>`
- `<meta>`
- `<script>`
- `<style>`
- `<title>`

There might be a couple more.

This is confusing because viewing just the documentation for the ID/class attributes doesn't specifically say that they can't be used with these elements. You have to look at the DTD for the elements to see that the general attributes are not defined for the element, and thus cannot be used.

---

**HTML 5 Answer:**

The default document type declaration, [HTMLElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#elements-in-the-dom), which applies to *all* elements in HTML specifies that these [global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#global-attributes) (including the ID attribute) can be used on any element you create, so it would appear you can do this in HTML 5, but not in HTML 4.

Comment: Never knew that about `id` being invalid on `<html>`, where did you get this list, from memory? I wonder at the reason for this as well. Your given reason, while probably valid, seems like it could be more technically accurate.

Comment: @Madmartigan: Looking at the [HTML 5 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#elements-in-the-dom), it looks like they've made these attributes global for all elements by default now. This seems to be HTML 4 specific, but I can't find the page for the `<html>` element from HTML 4.

Comment: Running an unofficial [html5 validator](http://html5.validator.nu/) passes the `id` attribute on `<script>`, so maybe it *is* valid in HTML5?

Comment: Even if you're using HTMl4, I can't imagine any browser you would care to support nowadays barfing on an ID attribute even if it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2):

Running a `<script>` tag with an `id` through [the validator](http://validator.w3.org/c) as HTML4 generates this error:

> Error Line 12, Column 12: there is no attribute "ID"

The [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) for `<script>` does not mention the [coreattrs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#coreattrs) (that include `class` and `id`) to be valid on this element:

```
18.2.1 The SCRIPT element

<!ELEMENT SCRIPT - - %Script;          -- script statements -->
<!ATTLIST SCRIPT
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED  -- char encoding of linked resource --
  type        %ContentType;  #REQUIRED -- content type of script language --
  src         %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- URI for an external script --
  defer       (defer)        #IMPLIED  -- UA may defer execution of script --
  >

Start tag: required, End tag: required
```

According to the [current HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element), `<script>` may have any [Global Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#global-attributes) which does include `id`. Testing this in an [unofficial HTML5 validator](http://html5.validator.nu/)  passes. So as far as I can tell:

- **Invalid** in HTML4
- **Valid** in HTML5