# Get URL of JavaScript File

Tags: javascript

location.href gives me the URL of the page I'm on. The page contains this:

```
<script src="http://mydomain/myscript.js"></script>
```

Inside of myscript.js is there a property that gives me the script URL ("http://mydomain/myscript.js")?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can code in a JavaScript file get the file's URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279195/how-can-code-in-a-javascript-file-get-the-files-url)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean, but i think that you want to find the src of all scripts. I found this to work:

```
 let array_of_src=[]
 document.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(function(element){array_of_src.push(element.src)})
 //do stuff with the array of all the srcs
```